# Shifting Chart Source Data Over 1 Column? VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having difficulties shifting the references over for a chart. I want to have a button that each time it is pressed it takes the current position of cell references which is four columns wide and shifts it over one column to the right. I recorded a macro but it only works one time, I want it to always take the current position and then move it over one column to the right. Below is the code from the recording.

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range( _
"'WTI Forward Prices'!$O$6:$O$36,'WTI Forward Prices'!$AC$6:$AF$36")
```

Comment: Are those four columns the four rightmost columns, or is there more data to the right?

Comment: They are the four rightmost columns.

Comment: Then you can find the last column and use `Resize` to grab the last four columns.

Comment: I'm able to find the last column and put it into a string or long variable but I'm not sure sure how to use the resize function and set the source data to it. Is there a way to just shift the current selection to the right by one column?

Comment: I think `Resize` is your best bet.